# Unable to see any section over the page when <FormSection> is used with reduxForm

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have used FormSection to separate some fields from remaining fields in my page. However all fields are being displayed normally with out any section. Here is my code,

```
render() {

    const { handleSubmit } = this.props; 

    return(
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label>First Name</label>
              <div>
                <Field name="firstName" 
                       component={this.renderField}  
                       type="text" 
                       focus={true}
                       placeholder="First Name"/>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Last Name</label>
              <div>
                <Field name="lastName" 
                       component={this.renderField} 
                       type="text" 
                       placeholder="Last Name"/>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="employee">Employee?</label>
              <div>
                <Field name="employee" 
                       className="fancy-checkbox-primary"
                       id="employee" 
                       component={this.renderField} 
                       onChange={event => {
                                       if(event.target.checked){
                                          this.setState({ disable : false });
                                       }
                                       else {
                                          this.setState({ disable : true });
                                       }
                                    }
                                } 
                       type="checkbox"/>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Salary</label>
              <div>
                <Field name="salary" 
                       component={this.renderField} 
                       type="number"
                       disabled={this.state.disable}
                       placeholder="Salary"/>
              </div>
          </div>

        /*****Here FormSection starts******/

          <FormSection name="EduDet" label="Education">
            <div>
            <label>X Standard</label>
              <div>
                <Field name="tenth" 
                       component={this.renderField}  
                       type="text" 
                       placeholder="School Name"/>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Intermediate</label>
              <div>
                <Field name="intermediate" 
                       component={this.renderField} 
                       type="text" 
                       placeholder="College Name"/>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Graduation</label>
              <div>
                <Field name="graduation" 
                       component={this.renderField} 
                       type="text" 
                       placeholder="College Name"/>       
              </div>
          </div>

          </FormSection>

          <div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> {''}
            <Link className="btn btn-danger" to="/" >
              Cancel
            </Link>
          </div>    
        </form> 

    );
}
```

}

I would like to see specific fields("tenth","intermediate","graduation" ) 
  to be wrapped inside a section .Do i need to add anything else to display the section? Please suggest something to solve the problem.

Comment: Not sure if I got your question correctly but the `FormSection` component is used to split forms into smaller ones which can be reused across multiple forms; nothing to do with the way Fields in the section are displayed. So if you want to wrap your inputs inside a section, just use the `section` tag like `<section> <FormSection name="EduDet" label="Education">....</FormSection></section>` and customize the UI as you want using CSS

Comment: @Dario, If the FormSection can be usable across multiple forms, Could  you tell me how can i export the FormSection from my current page!